# Show only MKOverlay part on Map

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, mapkit, offline, mkoverlay

I have created MKOverlay class & add it into the Map-view. Now i need to have some customisation in it as following :

- While opening it should only display MKOverlay & not show google map anywhere.
- Scrolling can only done in MKOverlay area.

To show only Overlay visible & hide google map area i have tried few things like to change alpha value of map & changing background colour of Map by checking tiles but not get any success yet.

**Note :** The reason why i want to hide the google map & show only MKOverlay visible is because i have implemented offline Map Feature. Thats why i can't show the original Map area just i have to show the overlay region.

Can anyone suggest how can i achieve this ?

Any suggestions or hints will be very useful to achieve this feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have use google map and change  mapView.mapType=kGMSTypeNone;  and set GMSGroundOverlay in map view is working

check this link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/overlays

Comment: can you please give some more detail ?